# Groovy sample application using queue and linked list

Tags: groovy, linked-list, queue

Can you please give me a sample application using Groovy which makes use of queue and linked list?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An exemple with a queue:

```
def q = ["elem1", "elem2"] as Queue

q.offer("inserted string")
assert q.peek() == "elem1"
assert q.poll() == "elem1"
assert q.poll() == "elem2"
assert q.poll() == "inserted string"
```

Here is an exemple with a linked list:

```
def l = [1, 2, 3] as LinkedList
assert l[0] == 1
l.add(4)
assert l.last() == 4
```

Comment: You can also use: q << 'inserted string'